# How to limit access of a single page on a team site to only certain members of the team

Tags: permissions, office, sharepoint-online

I have multiple pages on our team site, however some of the team members do not need access to two of the pages.Is it possible to restrict those two pages?  How is this done?

Comment: If they are pages in a document library like site pages you can set the permissions on each page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the "Shared with" menu from ribbon, go to "Advanced settings" from there, "Remove Inheritance" from the edit permissions page that opens from there. Now you could add/remove users from this page.

However I must suggest you to use groups of users (instead of individual users) to grant permissions here. So when you need to grant permissions to new users, you could add them directly to these groups.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose unique permissions for those two pages.

Open pages library, select the page, from ribbon -> Files Tab -> Shared With

Choose Advanced -> And From ribbon click on "Stop Inheriting Permission".. Now you can remove whoever you don't want to see the page.